# Azure pipelines hosted agents, specify image version

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-devops-hosted-agent

We are using the Azure hosted agent windows-2022 for our build. Without any changes our build is failing. I noticed that the last succeeded build used Image version '20221024.1', the failing is using version '20221027.1'.

This is creating some uncertainty because we don't know when new versions will arise. Is it possible to specify the older version and still use it until we resolve the issues with the new agent version.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure DevOps Services doesn't support to appoint specific older version for Microsoft-hosted agent. New versions may update some tools versions and thus may be the cause.

So we suggest using self-hosted agent, and you could install the needed tool version in the agent to run the affected pipeline, please see [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#what-can-i-do-if-software-i-need-is-removed-or-replaced-with-a-newer-version) for more details.

[image]